# regular expression for matching a pattern in Pattern class in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `m="hell,hj;nk,.txt"`

I want my string as string `m="hellhjnk.txt"`

I am using:

```
 Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\"([^\"]*)(\\.)([a-z]{1,4}[\"]))|'([^']+)(\\.)([a-z]{1,4})'");
```

It is working for double quotes and extension.
How it will work for removing space,comma,semicolon?

Answer (score 3):

You could just do:

```
m = m.replaceAll("[,; ]","");
```

The `Pattern` class is used for matching. You can essentially do the same thing:

```
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[;, ]");
     String m = "hell,hj;nk,.txt";
     Matcher matcher = p.matcher(m);
     System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));
```